# How can I get exposure times shorter than a second with an intervalometer?

Tags: timelapse

I am learning to do timelapses and I have a "Shoot" brand intervalometer.  The shortest exposure setting I can do on the intervalometer is 1 second.  If the exposure setting on my camera is set to something shorter/quicker than 1 second what should I set the intervalometer exposure to or is this even possible to do?

I was trying to do a timelapse  outside in daylight with an exposure set at 1/320 but like I said my intervalometer will only do 1 second, nothing shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you might be misunderstanding how an intervalometer works.  My suspicion is that the 1 second minimum is the *duration between exposures* and not the shutter speed.  For your example if you'd like a shutter speed of 1/320th of a second, configure that on your camera, and then configure the intervalometer to trigger the shutter however often you like.  With a minimum time of one second, in a minute you'd end up with 60 images each created with a shutter speed of 1/320th of a second.

Comment: Well you were absolutely right.  I feel stupid.  lol   I definitely didn't know how to use the intervalometer.  I got it now.  Thanks a lot for the response!!!

Comment: No worries.  Glad I was able to help out.  Enjoy your time lapse shooting!